# VB.net: Problems with Application.StartupPath

Tags: vb.net

I want to access the path of the folder that my published application has been run from.

Everything I can find says use Application.StartupPath(), but this doesn't work.

I wrote a simple program to display these, published to a single standalone file and then ran it from the directory `C:\Users\jerem\Downloads\split`.

This is what i got:

```
Application.StartupPath = "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\getlaunchdir\jvi1ji54.zau\"
Application.ExecutablePath = "C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\getlaunchdir\jvi1ji54.zau\getlaunchdir.dll"
```

It seems that running the .exe file creates a temp folder with a load of files in it that are then run.  Fine, but it returns the "wrong" results for StartupPath - i.e. not what I want.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

** image of publish settings added as requested by Caius Jard.
[picture of publish settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btGAq.png)

I'm not sure how you get your image showing application.startuppath as C:\temp\ - that looks like a debug mode shot and my problem only occurs while running the published program.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you published it with ClickOnce? If you publish it with Folder, it ought to behave as you expect

[image]

[image]

And when run:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - but I did publish to a folder.

Comment: Add the steps you took to your Q as screenshots; as you can see from the steps I put in my answer, I didn't have a problem doing a folder publish..

Answer (score 0):

Possibly might be what you are looking for:

```
Private uriBuilder As New UriBuilder(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)

    Public FullAssemblyPath As String = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uriBuilder.Path)
    Public ExeDirectory As String = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(FullAssemblyPath)
```

Comment: I get the same result with that - sorry.

Comment: Pity - looks like a 'Net Core' thing; targetting 'old' style 4.x frameworks doesn't produce those tortuous paths although Click-once does as the first answer suggests. Scott Hanselman has a blog post on this.